# Why isn't Fail2ban regenerating its iptables chains?

Tags: iptables, firewall, fail2ban, ubuntu-18.04

At some point while running `iptables -S` on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS system with Fail2ban installed, I noticed that the following lines were missing:

```
-N f2b-sshd
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

What command should I run to regenerate the **f2b-sshd** chain and all the rules associated with it? I tried running `fail2ban-client restart`, but this doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: What is your configured `banaction`?

Comment: In `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`? `iptables-multiport`. (I'm using the default configuration.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a `banaction` of `iptables-multiport` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` or `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, it looks like Fail2ban will automatically regenerate the **f2b-sshd** chain when it bans an IP address—*but no earlier*. If you'd like to test this for yourself, try running the following command to manually ban an address (like this one from [TEST-NET-1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735)):

```
# fail2ban-client -vvv set sshd banip 192.0.2.0
```

This behavior appears to be new in Fail2ban v0.10, which now [creates chains on demand](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1755#issuecomment-295286513) the first time an IP address is banned by an iptables action.