# fail2ban on Raspbian does not create iptables jails

Tags: ssh, iptables, fail2ban, raspbian

I installed fail2ban 0.10.2-2.1 on Raspbian Buster to protect ssh (and if that works, apache). The default installation only enables de sshd jail, but in my case that does not seem to work. The fail2ban-client reports that the jail is running:

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 0
|  `- File list:    /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

However, when I check if iptables rules are created, it shows no chains are created, and nothing is banned:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

As far as I understand, I expect a f2b-sshd chain to be in that list. I checked the logfile, and even when I configure fail2ban.conf to outout DEBUG level, I don't see any iptables actions:

```
2020-02-25 22:36:44,325 fail2ban.server         [28901]: INFO    --------------------------------------------------
2020-02-25 22:36:44,325 fail2ban.server         [28901]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.10.2
2020-02-25 22:36:44,327 fail2ban.server         [28901]: DEBUG   Creating PID file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
2020-02-25 22:36:44,327 fail2ban.server         [28901]: DEBUG   Starting communication
2020-02-25 22:36:44,332 fail2ban.database       [28901]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,337 fail2ban.jail           [28901]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,381 fail2ban.jail           [28901]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses pyinotify {}
2020-02-25 22:36:44,382 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterPyinotify(Jail('sshd'))
2020-02-25 22:36:44,382 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG   Created FilterPyinotify(Jail('sshd'))
2020-02-25 22:36:44,393 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[28901]: DEBUG   Created FilterPyinotify
2020-02-25 22:36:44,393 fail2ban.jail           [28901]: INFO    Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2020-02-25 22:36:44,396 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: INFO      maxLines: 1
2020-02-25 22:36:44,397 fail2ban.server         [28901]: DEBUG     prefregex: '^<F-MLFID>(?:\\[\\])?\\s*(?:<[^.]+\\.[^.]+>\\s+)?(?:\\S+\\s+)?(?:kernel: \\[ *\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\s+)?(?:@vserver_\\S+\\s+)?(?:(?:(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:\\s+[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?|[\\[\\(]?sshd(?:\\(\\S+\\))?[\\]\\)]?:?(?:\\[\\d+\\])?:?)\\s+)?(?:\\[ID \\d+ \\S+\\]\\s+)?</F-MLFID>(?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?<F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,413 fail2ban.server         [28901]: DEBUG     failregex: '^[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error|failed) for <F-USER>.*</F-USER> from <HOST>( via \\S+)?\\s*(?: \\[preauth\\])?\\s*$'
...SNIP...
2020-02-25 22:36:44,513 fail2ban.server         [28901]: DEBUG     failregex: '^<F-MLFFORGET><F-NOFAIL>Accepted publickey</F-NOFAIL></F-MLFFORGET> for \\S+ from <HOST>(?:\\s|$)'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,518 fail2ban.server         [28901]: DEBUG     failregex: '^<F-NOFAIL>Connection from</F-NOFAIL> <HOST>'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,524 fail2ban.datetemplate   [28901]: DEBUG     constructed regex (?:^|\b|\W)((?P<Y>(?:202|201)\d)(?P<_sep>[-/.])(?P<m>1[0-2]|0[1-9]|[1-9])(?P=_sep)(?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| [1-9])(?:T|  ?)(?P<H>2[0-3]|[0-1]\d|\d):(?P<M>[0-5]\d|\d):(?P<S>6[0-1]|[0-5]\d|\d)(?:[.,](?P<f>[0-9]{1,6}))?(?:\s*(?P<z>Z|UTC|GMT|[+-][01]\d(?::?\d{2})?))?)(?=\b|\W|$)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,525 fail2ban.datetemplate   [28901]: DEBUG     constructed regex ^(?:\W{0,2})?((?P<Y>(?:202|201)\d)(?P<_sep>[-/.])(?P<m>1[0-2]|0[1-9]|[1-9])(?P=_sep)(?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| [1-9])(?:T|  ?)(?P<H>2[0-3]|[0-1]\d|\d):(?P<M>[0-5]\d|\d):(?P<S>6[0-1]|[0-5]\d|\d)(?:[.,](?P<f>[0-9]{1,6}))?(?:\s*(?P<z>Z|UTC|GMT|[+-][01]\d(?::?\d{2})?))?)(?=\b|\W|$)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,526 fail2ban.datetemplate   [28901]: DEBUG     constructed regex (?:^|\b|\W)(?iu)((?:(?P<a>mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun) )?(?P<b>jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec) (?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| [1-9])  ?(?P<H>[0-2]?\d):(?P<M>[0-5]\d|\d):(?P<S>6[0-1]|[0-5]\d|\d)(?:\.(?P<f>[0-9]{1,6}))?(?: (?P<Y>(?:202|201)\d))?)(?=\b|\W|$)
...SNIP...
2020-02-25 22:36:44,544 fail2ban.datetemplate   [28901]: DEBUG     constructed regex ^(?:\W{0,2})?(?iu)((?:(?P<z>Z|UTC|GMT|[+-][01]\d(?::?\d{2})?) )?(?:(?P<a>mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun) )?(?P<b>jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec) (?P<d>3[0-1]|[1-2]\d|0[1-9]|[1-9]| [1-9])  ?(?P<H>[0-2]?\d):(?P<M>[0-5]\d|\d):(?P<S>6[0-1]|[0-5]\d|\d)(?:\.(?P<f>[0-9]{1,6}))?(?: (?P<Y>(?:202|201)\d))?)(?=\b|\W|$)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,545 fail2ban.datetemplate   [28901]: DEBUG     constructed regex (@[0-9a-f]{24})(?=\b|\W|$)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,545 fail2ban.datetemplate   [28901]: DEBUG     constructed regex ^(?:\W{0,2})?(@[0-9a-f]{24})(?=\b|\W|$)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,546 fail2ban.server         [28901]: INFO    Jail sshd is not a JournalFilter instance
2020-02-25 22:36:44,549 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: INFO    Added logfile: '/var/log/auth.log' (pos = 111389, hash = 88b5563c0ca8a36a0cc3a0fa6c6110a8a17ca4aa)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,550 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[28901]: DEBUG   New <Watch wd=1 path=/var/log mask=1073745280 proc_fun=None auto_add=False exclude_filter=<function WatchManager.<lambda> at 0x754a8e40> dir=True >
2020-02-25 22:36:44,551 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[28901]: DEBUG   Added monitor for the parent directory /var/log
2020-02-25 22:36:44,551 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[28901]: DEBUG   New <Watch wd=2 path=/var/log/auth.log mask=2 proc_fun=None auto_add=False exclude_filter=<function WatchManager.<lambda> at 0x754a8e40> dir=False >
2020-02-25 22:36:44,552 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[28901]: DEBUG   Added file watcher for /var/log/auth.log
2020-02-25 22:36:44,552 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG   Seek to find time 1582666004.5494933 (2020-02-25 22:26:44), file size 111470
2020-02-25 22:36:44,566 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG   Position 111389 from 111470, found time 1582666603.0 (2020-02-25 22:36:43) within 1 seeks
2020-02-25 22:36:44,568 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2020-02-25 22:36:44,569 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: INFO      maxRetry: 5
2020-02-25 22:36:44,570 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: INFO      findtime: 1800
2020-02-25 22:36:44,571 fail2ban.actions        [28901]: INFO      banTime: 1800
2020-02-25 22:36:44,572 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterPyinotify(Jail('sshd'))
2020-02-25 22:36:44,574 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG     Add '10.0.0.0/8' to ignore list ('10.0.0.21/8')
2020-02-25 22:36:44,575 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG     Add '127.0.0.0/8' to ignore list ('127.0.0.1/8')
2020-02-25 22:36:44,576 fail2ban.filter         [28901]: DEBUG     Add '::1' to ignore list ('::1')
2020-02-25 22:36:44,577 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG   Created <class 'fail2ban.server.action.CommandAction'>
2020-02-25 22:36:44,578 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actionstart = '<iptables> -N f2b-sshd\n<iptables> -A f2b-sshd -j RETURN\n<iptables> -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,579 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actionstop = '<iptables> -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd\n<iptables> -F f2b-sshd\n<iptables> -X f2b-sshd'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,579 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actionflush = '<iptables> -F f2b-sshd'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,579 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actioncheck = "<iptables> -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-sshd[ \\t]'"
2020-02-25 22:36:44,580 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actionban = '<iptables> -I f2b-sshd 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,580 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actionunban = '<iptables> -D f2b-sshd -s <ip> -j <blocktype>'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,580 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set name = 'sshd'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,581 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set bantime = '1800'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,581 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set port = 'ssh'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,581 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set protocol = 'tcp'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,581 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set chain = '<known/chain>'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,581 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set actname = 'iptables-multiport'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,582 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set blocktype = 'REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,582 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set returntype = 'RETURN'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,582 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set lockingopt = '-w'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,582 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set iptables = 'iptables <lockingopt>'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,583 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set blocktype?family=inet6 = 'REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,583 fail2ban.CommandAction  [28901]: DEBUG     Set iptables?family=inet6 = 'ip6tables <lockingopt>'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,584 fail2ban.jail           [28901]: DEBUG   Starting jail 'sshd'
2020-02-25 22:36:44,585 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[28901]: DEBUG   [sshd] filter started (pyinotifier)
2020-02-25 22:36:44,587 fail2ban.jail           [28901]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
```

I tried switching from pyinotify to gamin and polling mode to no avail. I tried creating separate configuration files, and adding explicit references to filter.d files, but nothing seems to help.

The regular expression matcher does report that matches are found:

```
$ fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : sshd, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         maxlines : 1
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /var/log/auth.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 19 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   6) [1] ^[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user <F-USER>.*?</F-USER> from <HOST>(?: port \d+)?(?: on \S+(?: port \d+)?)?\s*$
|  20) [18] ^<F-MLFFORGET><F-NOFAIL>Accepted publickey</F-NOFAIL></F-MLFFORGET> for \S+ from <HOST>(?:\s|$)
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1143] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 1143 lines, 0 ignored, 19 matched, 1124 missed
[processed in 0.81 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 1124 lines
```

It seems to me according to the documentation that the default installation of fail2ban should at least create iptables chains, which it does not do. What am I missing here?

Comment: One check I didn't do is a manual ban, such as described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/957675). I need to test that tonight and update this question with the results.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the answer is twofold. First, there is a change in how fail2ban works. Newer versions of fail2ban will not immediately create chains in the firewall configuration, but only upon first trigger. This explains why a new fail2ban installation does not show chains in iptables -L.

To test the creation of the iptables chains, we can use the `fail2ban-client` to add a ban (-vvv to add verbosity which may help you debug problems in the command):

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client -vvv set sshd banip 192.0.2.0
```

After running this command, iptables shows (should show) the chain for this jail:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  192.0.2.0            anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

We can unban the ip as follows:

```
$ sudo fail2ban-client -vvv set sshd unbanip 192.0.2.0
```

And now the rule in iptables is removed, *but the f2b-sshd chain persists*:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

In short, to test your fail2ban installation you must:

1. Install fail2ban with just the sshd configuration (which is default)
2. Use `sudo fail2ban-client status sshd` to check the status
3. Use `fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` to check the regular expression matching.
4. Use `sudo fail2ban-client -vvv set sshd banip 192.0.2.0` to generate an sshd ban
5. Use `sudo iptables -L` to verify that the f2b-sshd chain is created with the ban rule in it.
6. Use `sudo fail2ban-client -vvv set sshd unbanip 192.0.2.0` to remove the ban.

I also noticed that there is an option to revert the "on demand chain creation" behavior, check [this github issue for details](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1755#issuecomment-295286513)

I hope this helps.